# Rust: Can't import 1 module from 2 files

Tags: module, rust

This is my file structure:

```
src/
├── main.rs
├── args_parser.rs
└── trim.rs
```

In `args_parser.rs` I have enum `Args` that I want to use in `main.rs` and in `trim.rs`, but when trying to run `trim.rs` with `mod args_parser;` at the beginning it spits out this error message:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `args_parser`
 --> src/trim.rs:1:5
  |
1 | mod args_parser;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: name the file either trim/args_parser.rs or trim/args_parser/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

It seems like it expects trim.rs to import only files that are from this module, but in Rust by example (https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) it says "This declaration will look for a file named `my.rs` or `my/mod.rs`".

Is there any way I can import this file from `main.rs` and from `trim.rs`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up declaring a module (`mod <name>`) and importing a module (`use <name>`). The `mod` keyword is used to declare a new module, either in another file, or with curly braces immediately following the keyword. You can then import the module with `use`.

When using `mod` to declare a module in another file, it looks in specific locations. For example, when you use the following statement in `main.rs`, `mod.rs`, or `lib.rs`...

```
mod abc;
```

...the compiler will search for contents of the module in `./abc.rs` and `abc/mod.rs`. However, if I have the same statement in a different file, like `def.rs`, it will instead check in `def/abc.rs` and `def/abc/mod.rs`. This is why your code isn't compiling.

To fix this, declare the module in your main file, and then import it elsewhere. This is what the code would look like:

```
// in main.rs
mod args_parser;
mod trim;
use args_parser::...; // use whatever you need in main

// in trim.rs
use crate::args_parser::...; // use whatever you need in trim - note the crate:: prefix
```

Comment: I thought that `mod` was for importing. Thanks for clearing things up and through explanation! Have a nice day!